# PowerShell: group commands together, for redirect output

Tags: powershell

How to group commands together in PowerShell, for redirect output for e.g.?

Here is what I do in normal Unix shell:

```
{ echo a; echo b; echo c; } > testout

$ cat testout
a
b
c
```

All three (different) commands' output are redirect to the same file.

Is that possible in PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that in PowerShell too.
You can use the same syntax as you use in Unix in this example.

However, one thing you should add before this code block is call operator `&`, or otherwise what you wrote inside it will be printed literally.

So use this:

```
&{echo a; echo b; echo c;} > testout
cat testout
```

Output is:

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 2):

Another use for $() besides inside strings...

```
$(Echo a; Echo b; Echo c) > testout
```